# Firebase won't update data

Tags: javascript, firebase

So.. After submitting the form, The user will get a friendly message in a alert and the data will update.

The code :

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dr-iqbal.firebaseio.com/"),
  date = new Date(),
  right_now = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate(),
  today = ref.child(right_now);
  no_antri = new Firebase("https://dr-iqbal.firebaseio.com/no_antrian");

no_antri.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        swal({
          title: "Masih Tersedia",
          text: "Anda masih bisa mendapatkan nomor antrian karena " + "<br>" + "masih ada tempat" + "<br>" + "<br>" + "Nomor antrian: " + snapshot.val(),
          type: "success",
          html: true
        })
      no_antri.update({
       no_antri: snapshot.val() + 1
      });
      })
```

The code that I write actually replace the data with `1 [Object] [object]` 
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(snapshot.val())`?

Comment: The question mentions 'data will update'. Are you *adding* new data or do you want to *update* existing data. There are a few issues with the code but the answer will depend on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your JSON is:

```
"no_antrian": {
    "no_antrian": 2
}
```

Since you're reading from `/no_antrian`, you're getting an object and not just the value `2`.

Once solution would be to:

```
no_antri.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  no_antri.update({
   no_antri: snapshot.val().no_antri + 1
  });
})
```

Comment: You will have to be a bit more descriptive than that if you want us to be able to help. Can you set up a jsbin/jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?